# Erro ao utilizar bootstrap com ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap, metronic

Estou com o erro ao utilizar o bootstrap.min.js, o erro é que não encontra uma função. Segue erro abaixo e configuração do meu sistema. É preciso postar mais alguma coisa para poderem me ajudar encontrar o problema?

> Erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Função que da erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> _Layout

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--http://localhost:6950/Metronic/theme/assets/global/css/components-rounded.min.css
Template Name: Metronic - Responsive Admin Dashboard Template build with Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.7
Version: 4.7
Author: KeenThemes
Website: http://www.keenthemes.com/
Contact: support@keenthemes.com
Follow: www.twitter.com/keenthemes
Dribbble: www.dribbble.com/keenthemes
Like: www.facebook.com/keenthemes
Purchase: http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469?ref=keenthemes
Renew Support: http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469?ref=keenthemes
License: You must have a valid license purchased only from themeforest(the above link) in order to legally use the theme for your project.
-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="pt-br">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Projeto Web ERP</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="#1 selling multi-purpose bootstrap admin theme sold in themeforest marketplace packed with angularjs, material design, rtl support with over thausands of templates and ui elements and plugins to power any type of web applications including saas and admin dashboards. Preview page of Theme #1 for statistics, charts, recent events and reports"
          name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES
        
        <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/jqvmap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/css/components-rounded.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_components" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/css/plugins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/layouts/layout/css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/layouts/layout/css/themes/darkblue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color" />
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/layouts/layout/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-toastr/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-toastr/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @RenderSection("styles", required: false)
</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->
<body class="page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo page-content-white">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
        <div class="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <!-- BEGIN HEADER INNER -->
            <div class="page-header-inner ">
                <!-- BEGIN LOGO -->
                <div class="page-logo">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/layouts/layout/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo-default" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="menu-toggler sidebar-toggler">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END LOGO -->
                <!-- BEGIN RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
                <a href="javascript:;" class="menu-toggler responsive-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span></span>
                </a>
                <!-- END RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
                <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
                <div class="top-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <!-- BEGIN NOTIFICATION DROPDOWN -->
                        <!-- DOC: Apply "dropdown-dark" class after below "dropdown-extended" to change the dropdown styte -->
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-user">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
                                <img alt="" class="img-circle" src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/layouts/layout/img/avatar3_small.jpg" />
                                <span class="username username-hide-on-mobile"> Nick </span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-default">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="page_user_profile_1.html">
                                        <i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="app_calendar.html">
                                        <i class="icon-calendar"></i> My Calendar
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="app_inbox.html">
                                        <i class="icon-envelope-open"></i> My Inbox
                                        <span class="badge badge-danger"> 3 </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="app_todo.html">
                                        <i class="icon-rocket"></i> My Tasks
                                        <span class="badge badge-success"> 7 </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"> </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="page_user_lock_1.html">
                                        <i class="icon-lock"></i> Lock Screen
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="page_user_login_1.html">
                                        <i class="icon-key"></i> Log Out
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- END USER LOGIN DROPDOWN -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
            </div>
            <!-- END HEADER INNER -->
        </div>
        <!-- END HEADER -->
        <!-- BEGIN HEADER & CONTENT DIVIDER -->
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        <!-- END HEADER & CONTENT DIVIDER -->
        <!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
        <div class="page-container">
            <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
            <div class="page-sidebar-wrapper">
                <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
                <!-- DOC: Set data-auto-scroll="false" to disable the sidebar from auto scrolling/focusing -->
                <!-- DOC: Change data-auto-speed="200" to adjust the sub menu slide up/down speed -->
                <div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU -->
                    <!-- DOC: Apply "page-sidebar-menu-light" class right after "page-sidebar-menu" to enable light sidebar menu style(without borders) -->
                    <!-- DOC: Apply "page-sidebar-menu-hover-submenu" class right after "page-sidebar-menu" to enable hoverable(hover vs accordion) sub menu mode -->
                    <!-- DOC: Apply "page-sidebar-menu-closed" class right after "page-sidebar-menu" to collapse("page-sidebar-closed" class must be applied to the body element) the sidebar sub menu mode -->
                    <!-- DOC: Set data-auto-scroll="false" to disable the sidebar from auto scrolling/focusing -->
                    <!-- DOC: Set data-keep-expand="true" to keep the submenues expanded -->
                    <!-- DOC: Set data-auto-speed="200" to adjust the sub menu slide up/down speed -->
                    <ul class="page-sidebar-menu  page-header-fixed " data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200" style="padding-top: 20px">
                        <!-- DOC: To remove the sidebar toggler from the sidebar you just need to completely remove the below "sidebar-toggler-wrapper" LI element -->
                        <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
                        <li class="sidebar-toggler-wrapper hide">
                            <div class="sidebar-toggler">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- END SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
                        <li class="heading">
                            <h3 class="uppercase">Features</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item  ">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                                <i class="icon-diamond"></i>
                                <span class="title">Cadastros</span>
                                <span class="arrow"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="nav-item  ">
                                    <a href="ui_colors.html" class="nav-link ">
                                        <span class="title">Pais</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item  ">
                                    <a href="ui_general.html" class="nav-link ">
                                        <span class="title">Estado</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item  ">
                                    <a href="ui_buttons.html" class="nav-link ">
                                        <span class="title">Cidade</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                </div>
                <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
            </div>
            <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
            <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                <div class="page-content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END CONTENT -->
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTAINER -->
        <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
        <div class="page-footer">
            <div class="page-footer-inner">
                2016 &copy; Metronic Theme By
                <a target="_blank" href="http://keenthemes.com">Keenthemes</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                <a href="http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469?ref=keenthemes" title="Purchase Metronic just for 27$ and get lifetime updates for free" target="_blank">Purchase Metronic!</a>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll-to-top">
                <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END FOOTER -->
    </div>


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/ie8.fix.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS -->
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/morris/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/counterup/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/pie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/radar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/themes/light.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/themes/patterns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/themes/chalk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/ammap/ammap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/ammap/maps/js/worldLow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amstockcharts/amstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/horizontal-timeline/horizontal-timeline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.categories.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jquery-easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.russia.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.europe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.germany.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/data/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/scripts/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/pages/scripts/dashboard.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS -->

    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/layouts/layout/scripts/layout.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/layouts/layout/scripts/demo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-sidebar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-nav.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-toastr/toastr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootbox/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-confirmation/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-confirmation/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
    <!-- END THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS -->
        
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Qual o tipo de servidor local está usando, ISS, ISS Express?

Como sugestão de correção podemos tentar:

Visto que o caminho do erro do GET que vem de .../fonts/... e pelo tipo de extensão no final também ".woff2", pode ser erro de falta de tipos de MIME cujo teria de adicionar o tipo de MIME no servidor.

Usando ISS: 
Siga os passos:
 -> Abra o ISS
 -> Clique na no seu servidor ativo
 -> Encontre nas opções Type MIME e abra
 -> Nas ferramentas ao lado, clique em Add...
 -> Na caixa que abrir preencha com 
 -> FILE NAME EXTENSION: ".woff2"
 -> MIME TYPE: "application/font-woff2"
 -> Clique Ok, reinicie o servidor

Usando ISSEXPRESS:
Coloque no seu "web.config"

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```